# Why is DMARC Passing, when it seems like there is no alignment?

Tags: dkim, dmarc

I have set adkim=s and aspf=s, the DMARC check on mxtoolbox.com passes all tests. However, I'm using the default DKIM from microsoft, so from my understanding DMARC should fail since the alignment check with DKIM should fail. However, it passes:

```
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   dkim=pass header.i=@examplecom.onmicrosoft.com header.s=selector2-examplecom-onmicrosoft-com header.b=bdMHamqv;
   arc=pass (i=1 spf=pass spfdomain=example.com dkim=pass dkdomain=example.com dmarc=pass fromdomain=example.com);
   spf=pass (google.com: domain of jsmith@example.com designates 4b14:222:c200:5a2a::315 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=jsmith@example.com;
   dmarc=pass (p=REJECT sp=REJECT dis=NONE) header.from=example.com

DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=examplecom.onmicrosoft.com; s=selector2-examplecom-onmicrosoft-com; ...
```

Clearly the d=examplecom.onmicrosoft.com is not the same as header.from=example.com... so why is DMARC passing anyways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For DMARC to pass it is enough that **either** SPF or DKIM passes and is aligned. In your specific case DMARC `header.from=example.com` which is aligned with the SPF `smtp.mailfrom=jsmith@example.com` and the SPF is passing.

Comment: Thanks, that explains another confusion I had, when DKIM was failing but DMARC passed (because SPF passed along with alignment).

Comment: If you want to force DKIM validity, change your SPF record to e.g. `v=spf1 ?all` and then SPF will never pass. (That may be aggressive; maybe some emailed logs come from servers that don't use DKIM. After changing your SPF, revert back to DMARC `p=quarantine` and re-vet your DMARC aggregated logs to be sure.)